# Does pagination on static HTML table help improve performance

Tags: javascript, html, performance, html-table

I have a big HTML table (~10K rows, 4 columns, text only) dumped from a database. I'm experiencing poor performance when opening it in Chrome/Firefox.

I do not have direct access to database, so it is impossible to load page by page. All data is static HTML.

Does pagination with some jQuery plugin help improve performance in this case? Any other suggestions?

Comment: imho, yes. At least GPU will have less to render.

Comment: Can you separate the pages using PHP?

That would improve performance.

Comment: You might also want to consider making a real spreadsheet or at least a csv. Doing anything with 10k rows in a browser is not pleasant...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem and made a jQuery plugin:

https://github.com/lperrin/infinitable

To use it, you can load all your data with Ajax call, turn it into a huge array, and pass it to the plugin.

It basically hides cells that are not visibles, while making it easy to sort or filter cells. There are other solutions to achieve that, but this one has no dependencies besides jQuery.

The project contains a demo with a table containing 100,000 elements.

Answer (score 3):

When applicable, setting `table-layout: fixed` helps in reducing rendering time a lot. The slowness is mostly caused by the fact that in the default table layout method, the browser has to parse and process the entire table, calculating width requirements for all cells, before it can render any part of the table.

Fixed layout tells the browser to set column widths according to the first row (paying attention to any CSS that may apply to it). This may, of course, result in a mess, if the widths are not suitable for other rows. For a data table where rows are generally very similar, the widths can probably be set suitably.

This does not change the issue that very few people, if any, are going to read all the 10,000 rows. People will probably be looking for some specific data there. It might be better to set up a search form that lets the user get just what he wants.

Answer (score 0):

Pagination would most certainly solve this problem. You could also try initially setting the table style to `display: none`. Although the pagination should likely take effect before the browser attempts to render the table.

You could also store the table in a separate html file, do an ajax call to the document, and implement [live scrolling](http://www.fieg.nl/infinite-ajax-scroll-a-jquery-plugin). Although, this depends on how you expect the user to explore the data. If jumping to a particular rage like `100-199` is useful, a [paginated table](http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-pagination-plugins/#.UBn8T2HXG8A) would be ideal.